# Accessing mySQL using EASYPHP DEVSERVER on command line

Tags: php, mysql, installation

The book I'm reading asked me to type

```
"\Program Files\EasyPHP 3.0\mysql\bin\mysql" -u root
```

in my command line, but my `mysql` executable directory, which I installed using with `EASYPHP DEVSERVER`, is in

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\mysql\bin
```

So I tried making sense of it (or at least that's what I thought) and tried typing

```
"\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\mysql\bin" -u root
```

in the command line. I pressed enter and I got an error that that's `unrecognizable`.

So how do I access my database through the command line? Did I make any installation errors? Are there misconceptions I have?

Comment: Perhaps it is trying to access the `C:/` directory instead of `D:/` ?

Comment: You are missing the last "mysql" in your command. The way you have your command at the moment, you are asking to run "bin" and not "mysql"

Comment: @DarkAshelin, but my Windows is running in D:/ and not C:/ drive.

Comment: @BerndLinde, I tried running mysql the way you suggested and it gave me the same error.

Comment: @SelloNyama Can you try `"D:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\mysql\bin\mysql" -u root` ?

Answer (score 0):

Change `"\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\mysql\bin" -u root` to `"D:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\mysql\bin" -u root`

The writer assumed everything was on the same windows partition.

Also I advise you to add mysql to your `PATH` for convenience: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23841529/982075

Answer (score 0):

C:\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\dbserver\mysql5717x86x200727173959\bin>mysql -u root
And Enter
\bin>mysql -u root

Comment: `bin>mysql` ? Are you sure ?