# local mysql connect ECONNREFUSED only on windows

Tags: mysql, node.js, windows, xampp

I've tried everything, but simply on windows any connection to the database is refused, I used xampp, manp, easyphp and mysql workbench, but everyone had the same problem. the xampp in linux works perfectly with the same code, however in windows and refused, I tried to turn off the firewall too and give permissions, but it also didn't help, I saw that there was the mysql process, but still nothing.

I am using the following code just to test whether it is connecting.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host:"localhost",
  user:"root",
  port: 3306,
  password:""
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

And the exit

```
/mnt/d/Projetos/EstudoNode/teste.js:11
  if (err) throw err;
           ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/mnt/d/Projetos/EstudoNode/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/mnt/d/Projetos/EstudoNode/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/mnt/d/Projetos/EstudoNode/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)      
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/Projetos/EstudoNode/teste.js:10:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

I'm trying to make it work with xampp, I've tried to change the port but in this case windows defender blocks myql from starting.

I've been trying all kinds of solutions for two days, but I have no idea what to do

edit1: I just noticed that it is also giving this error in xampp, I don't know if it may be influencing the connection.

[image]

edit2: I tried to connect with the php code below and I was successful with the connection, so I believe it is some problem with nodejs on windows.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: try first to connect t´with the mysql client, if this will also nzt work, you must check the confguration and wtat grants the user rt has. what you also can try is using 127.0.0.0.1 insteqad f localhost

Comment: already tried with 127.0.0.1 how do I try to connect with the mysql client?

Comment: simply use `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p`

Comment: Windows cmd does not recognize the mysql command

Comment: It is there ,you must find where it is installed, like `C:\Program Files\MySQL Server xxx\bin`. chdir into that path and run mysql.exe with the connection arguments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805567/getting-mysql-path-in-command-prompt

Comment: The command worked, entered the MariaDB panel

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not part of xampp or any database. the problem and the windows WSL that is not allowing the connection